# Print the results of regular expression Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to display some text based on the some  condition (i.e. `if` the regular expression is matched) and keep on prompting the user to enter some text or stop in prompt.

I have used `do-while` but its not printing the results every time until I enter stop in the prompt window.

All the statements given in the `document.getelementbyId` is not getting printed.

- Create 4 regular expressions:

  - match a string that contains at least one character in A-Z, a-z, 0-9 and _
  - match a string that does not contain a number between 0 and 9
  - search for an uppercase letter, followed by one or more lowercase letters, followed by a space.
  - find a # sign, followed by excatly 5 repeating digits, a period, and another digit
- Prompt for the user to enter a text.
- Test the text against each regular expression.
- Display "It's a match" or "No match" after each test.
- Repeat until the user enter "stop" and test the last time and exit.

It's homework for me but I tried it's not working. Please help.

```js
function matchRegularExpr() {
  var text1 = "";
  document.getElementById("text1").innerHTML = ("<h1>The text is: " + text1 + "</h1></br>");
  document.getElementById("pattern1").innerHTML = ("Match a string that contains at least one character in A-Z, a-z, 0-9 and _</br>");
  document.getElementById("pattern2").innerHTML = "Match a string that does not contain a number between 0 and 9";
  document.getElementById("pattern3").innerHTML = "Search for an uppercase letter, folowed by one or more lowercase letters, followed by a space.";
  document.getElementById("pattern4").innerHTML = "Find a # sign, followed by excatly 5 repeating digits, a period, and another digit";
    
  do {
    text1 = window.prompt("Enter the text(stop to exit)", "stop");
    if (text1 === "stop") { break; } 
    var re1 = /\w/g;      //\w – is the same as [a-zA-Z0-9_],
    var re2 = /[^0-9]/g;  //[^0-9] – any character except a digit, the same as \D.
    var re3 = /[A-Z][a-z]/g;
    var re4 = /\W\d{5}\.\d/g;
    if (re1.test(text1)) {
      document.getElementById("match1").innerHTML += "\n" + text1 + "It's a Match";
   } else {
      document.getElementById("nomatch1").innerHTML += "\n" + text1 + "It's not a Match";
   }           
    
    if (re2.test(text1)) {
      document.getElementById("match2").innerHTML += "\n" + text1 + "It's a Match";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("nomatch2").innerHTML += "\n" + text1 + "It's not a Match";
    }

    if (re3.test(text1)) {
      document.getElementById("match3").innerHTML += "\n" + text1 + "It's a Match";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("nomatch3").innerHTML += "\n" + text1 + "It's not a Match";
    }

    if (re4.test(text1)) {
      document.getElementById("match4").innerHTML += "\n" + text1 + "It's a Match";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("nomatch4").innerHTML += "\n" + text1 + "It's not a Match";
    }
    
  } while (text1 != "stop");    
};

matchRegularExpr();
```

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    
    <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Lab12 Regular Expression</title>
     
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#efe862">
        <p id="text1"></p>
        <p id="pattern1">  </p>
        <p id="match1"> </p>
        <p id="notmatch1"></p>
        <p id="pattern2"></p>
        <p id="match2"> </p>
        <p id="nomatch2"></p>
        <p id="pattern3"> </p>
        <p id="match3"></p>
        <p id="nomatch3"></p>
        <p id="pattern4"> </p>
        <p id="match4"></p>
        <p id="nomatch4"></p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your question is that you want the text "stop" to stop the search and not get tested itself, right? Well, you could easily do that using a while loop and doing some modifications:

```
 var text1 = prompt("Enter some text (stop to exit)", "stop")
 while(text1 != "test") {
    // do all the searches exactly as in your code but without assigning text1 at the begining
    // ...
    // reassign text1 at the end so that the condition is checked before the code runs
   text1 = prompt("Enter some text (stop to exit)", "stop")
 }
```